# Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Please help me.
I see error: 
Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in

From code

```
<?php
include 'koneksi.php';
$konek = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM member ORDER By id ASC');
if ($konek){
    echo 'Could not run query :' .mysqli_error();
    exit;
}
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($konek)){
    echo (' $row[0] | $row [1] | $row[2] <br/>');
}
?>
```

Comment: `if (!$konek){` , `echo $row[0].' | '.$row[1].' | '.$row[2].'<br/>';}` ,  `mysqli_query($connection,'SELECT * FROM member ORDER By id ASC');`

Answer (score 4):

Your code is fundamentally broken:

mysqli expects its connection handle as the first argument, but you're passing in a query string:

```
$konek = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM member ORDER By id ASC');
```

It should be:

```
$konek = mysqli_query($database_handle, 'SELECT ...');
```

Then there's:

```
if ($konek){
```

mysqli returns boolean false on failure, or a statement handle on success. You need to do

```
if (!$konek)
```

to test for that false, otherwise the statement handle will always evaluate to "true" and you falsely output your error notice.

PHP strings with `'` quotes do **NOT** expand variable values:

```
echo (' $row[0] | $row [1] | $row[2] <br/>');
```

so this code will output `$`, `r`, `o`, etc..., not the contents of those variables. You need to use `"` quotes instad:

```
echo ("$row[0] | $row [1] | $row[2] <br/>");
```

and then there's `$row [1]`. Note the space in there. PHP will output the following for that:

```
Array [1]
```

because the space "breaks" your array reference. So in total, you need

```
 echo (" $row[0] | $row[1] | $row[2] <br/>");
```

And note that `echo` is not a function, you do NOT need to use `()` around its arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your error is caused because your passing a `string` instead of the `conn` variable.

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

```
mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

You are passing the query and not the `$link` to the mysqli connection. You need to pass both:

```
$konek = mysqli_query($YOUR_LINK, 'SELECT * FROM member ORDER By id ASC');
```

Also you have many others errors that are covered by the others answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is backwards

```
$konek = mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM member ORDER By id ASC');
if ($konek){
```

So if `$konek` is successful you throw your error. Try this

```
if(!$konek) {
```

Comment: also, OP is missing the connection link -> `$konek = mysqli_query(**$conn**, 'SELECT...`

Comment: There's several other problems with his post as well. I only addressed the question itself